# How i can remove Working Functionality of my header & footer plugin from backend files but in front end plugin need to show that plugin activate

Tags: plugins, code

I have a question actually I have a website in which one of my friends is using too many scripts in the header & footer using header & footer plugin in WordPress so I just want to stop the functionality of plugin from backend files but I want to show plugin works perfectly on the front but stop from the back end is there any way to do this please help...
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to remove the Header & Footer plugin from the site, and instead use Google Tag Manager. GTM plugins should only insert scripts on the front end and not in the admin, and GTM itself has a separate dashboard where users can add and remove scripts, so no deployment is needed, just like with the plugin you're currently using.